# Grep last match of returned multi line result and assign to variable

Tags: bash, grep

Lets say that I have a command `list kittens` that returns something in this multi line format in my terminal (in this exact layout):

```
[ 'fluffy'
  'buster'
  'bob1' ]
```

How can I fetch *bob1* and assign to a variable for scripting use? Here's my non working try so far.

```
list kittens | grep "'([^']+)' \]"
```

I am not overly familiar with grepping on the cli and am running into issues of syntax with quotes and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `bob1` will be in the last line, you can capture it like that:

```
myvar="$(list kittens | tail -n1 | grep -oP "'\K[^']+(?=')")"
```

This uses `tail` to find the last line and then `grep` with a lookahead and a lookbehind in the regular expression to extract the part inside the quotes.

**Edit**: The above assume that you are using GNU `grep` (for the `-P` mode). Here's an alternative with `sed`:

```
myvar="$(list kittens | tail -n1 | sed -e "s/^[^']*'//; s/'[^']*$//")"
```

Comment: So I am running into an issue - one that I have been dealing with from various examples. I am on OSX so perhaps a diff grep - when I run this I get a grep usage dump (Usage: grep.. etc..). It seems that 'P' is not a valid option. I have grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

Comment: Seems that 'P is only available in some instances. But since I have only one line I can work with that. Thank you.

Comment: @Yashua Sorry, I shouldn't have assumed that you have GNU grep, I added an alternative solution with sed.

Answer (score 1):

Could be done by `awk` alone:

```
list kittens |awk 'END{gsub(/\047|[[:blank:]]|\]/,"");print $0}'
bob1
```

Example:

```
 echo "$kit"
[ 'fluffy'
  'buster'
  'bob1' ]
echo "$kit"  |awk 'END{gsub(/\047|[[:blank:]]|\]/,"");print $0}'
bob1
```

To Assign it to any variable:

```
var=$(list kittens |awk 'END{gsub(/\047|[[:blank:]]|\]/,"");print $0}'
```

*Explanation*:

*`END{}`: End block is used to take data from last line as we are interested only for last line. 
`gsub`: This is `awk's` inbuilt function for search and replacement tasks. Here  white space and double quoted and single quotes are removed. Not that `\047` is used for single quote replacement.*